# error while using python open cv libary and keyboard libary

Tags: python

when I try to run this code with the keyboard library the webcam is not working why? I don't wanna use wait key method ( it works fine with the wait key method)

```
import cv2
import keyboard
webcam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
        ret,frame=webcam.read()
        cv2.imshow("webcam",frame)
        if  keyboard.read_key() == 'esc': break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
webcam.release()
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the documentation?  `keyboard.read_key()` blocks until a key is pressed.  Your loop won't get any farther.

You probably wanted `keyboard.is_pressed('esc')` instead.

Comment: mm I tried it still not working

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: webcam not launching

Comment: Have you added debug print statements so you actually know how far it gets?

Answer (score 0):

press `c` in your keyborad, it will break it.

```
import cv2
# import keyboard
webcam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
        ret,frame=webcam.read()
        cv2.imshow("webcam",frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord("c"): 
            break
        elif key == ord("r"):  
            pass
        elif key == ord("q"):  
           pass

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
webcam.release()
```

Comment: bro i don't want to use wait key method

Comment: Sorry, then. bro